# JavaScript: How to flag words in a string to be shown in a different colour where each char of the string is appended to an element one by one?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a function that takes in a string (e.g. "Hello World!") and appends each character of the string to an HTML element with a delay in between each character (i.e. creating a type writer effect).

I want to flag certain words in the string and colour it (e.g. "Hello") so that each character printed is coloured.

I've seen other examples of this but all of them have the string hardcoded or do not allow the colouring of certain words.

I've tried inserting characters (e.g. ☺) into the string as a flag and when I encounter these, I colour every letter until I encounter it again.

```js
// start with this string
let originalStr = "Hello Wor☺ld";

// insert "☺" at the start and end of "Wor☺ld"
let str = "Hello ☺Wor☺ld☺!";
let isFlagged = false;
str = str.split("");

str.forEach(function(item){
    if (item ==="☺" && !isFlagged){
        isFlagged = true;
    }else if (item === "☺" && isFlagged){
        isFlagged = false;
    }else if (isFlagged){
        console.log(item + " red");
    }else{
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```

Desired output is each char of "Wor☺ld" is logged with " red" appended to it. 
Here, "Wor" is correctly flagged, but "☺ld" is not.

This works fine but breaks if "☺" already existed within the string and I'm wondering if there's a better way to handle the flagging of words.

Comment: I think it would be easier to make an array of words you want to be colored. Then split the string on a space character so you have all words in an array. Loop through that array coloring the words you want colored. Then put it back together and output the result.

Comment: oh this gave me the idea to just create an element for every word and just append the chars of a word to these elements. Removes the issue of having an element for each char as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to set flage true instead of false in first else if condition. I hope it will help you.

```js
let originalStr = "Hello Wor☺ld";

// insert "☺" at the start and end of "Wor☺ld"
var str = "Hello ☺Wor☺ld☺!";
let isFlagged = false;
str = str.split("");

str.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item === "☺" && !isFlagged) {
isFlagged = true;
  } else if (item === "☺" && isFlagged) {
isFlagged = true;
  } else if (isFlagged) {
console.log(item + " red");
  } else {
console.log(item);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
let textString = "Hello ☺Wor☺ld. Hello, ☺world☺ !"

let reg = /☺(.*?)☺/ig

let ocurrences = Array.from(textString.matchAll(reg))
let ranges = ocurrences.map(ocurrence => { 
  return {
    start: ocurrence.index, 
    end: ocurrence.index + ocurrence[1].length + 1
   }
})

let parsedText = textString.split('').map((char, charIndex) => {

   let rangesThatContainsChar = ranges.filter( range => {
                    return charIndex > range.start && charIndex < range.end
                 })
   let isInside = rangesThatContainsChar.length === 0
              
   return isInside ? char : char + ' red'
           
})


parsedText.forEach(char => console.log(char))
```